# How to extract a line in Java using indexOf()

Tags: java, extract, indexof

the code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExtractLine
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);
    String songs =
    "1. Bow Wow - Fresh Azimiz\n" +
    "2. Weezer - Beverly Hills\n" +
    "3. Dave Matthews Band - Crash Into Me\n" +
    "4. Sheryl Crow - Leaving Las Vegas\n";

    String songNum; //song number that is searched for
    //int songIndex; //position of where song number is found
    int eolIndex; //position of end of line character
    String song; //the specified line

    System.out.print ("Enter song number: ");
    songNum = stdIn.nextLine();
    eolIndex = songs.indexOf("\n");


    int songIndex = songs.indexOf(songNum);


    song = songs.substring(songIndex);

    System.out.println("\n\n" + song + "\n\n");


}//end main
}//end class
```

what needs to happen is the user has to input a number, 1-4, then the output will be just that line with the song on it, eg. user input: 1, output: 1. Bow Wow - Fresh Azimiz. (not my choice, this is something out of a textbook).

My problem, I can get the program to recognize that it needs to start at whatever number i input, the output just happens to have everything, not just the line.

eg: input: 3

output: 3. Dave Matthews Band - Crash Into Me (\n)
        4. Sheryl Crow - Leaving Las Vegas

any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [one-argument `substring` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) you call takes from the beginning position through the end of the string, which is not what you want.

You will need to find the index of the *next* `\n` character.  If it exists, then use [the two-argument `substring` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) that will extract the proper substring.  If it doesn't exist, then you can call `substring` as you already call it -- to get the substring through to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a collection to store your songs (for example a HashMap). That way you can access the value directly from the key, without having to worry about accessing the substrings.

Here's one way of doing it (**note**, you'll receive a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the user enters anything except an integer, and a null object if the key isn't found):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<Integer, String> songs = new HashMap<>();
    songs.put(1, "Bow Wow - Fresh Azimiz");
    songs.put(2, "Weezer - Beverly Hills");
    songs.put(3, "Dave Matthews Band - Crash Into Me");
    songs.put(4, "Sheryl Crow - Leaving Las Vegas");

    Integer songNum; 
    System.out.print("Enter song number: ");
    songNum = Integer.valueOf(stdIn.nextLine());

    System.out.println("\n\n" + songs.get(songNum) + "\n\n");
    stdIn.close();
}
```

Comment: I realize now that the question pertains to the use indexOf, and not simply how to get the right song string. Should I delete this answer?